# i need Apostrophe in a variable result MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I receive data in this format like:

```
C00001,C00302,C00303,C00287,C00286,C00285,C00017
```

in a variable but i need in this shape:

```
'C00001','C00302','C00303','C00287','C00286','C00285','C00017'
```

i am new in mysql kindly any help

Comment: How are you getting this data?  Is your data literally stored as a comma separated string?

Comment: yes my data is stored coma separated in a field like jobe_code field has C00001,C00302,C00303,C00287,C00286,C00285,C00017 in one record

Comment: PROTIP: Don't store more than one value in a field.

Comment: @user2964497 by who ? Because its plain wrong to do it that way.

Answer (score 2):

You can `explode` the data, modify it, then re-`implode` it.

```
$data = 'C00001,C00302,C00303,C00287,C00286,C00285,C00017';

$arr = explode(',', $data);
$new_arr = array_map(function($a){
    return "'{$a}'";
}, $arr);

$new_data = implode(',', $new_arr);
```